# How to bundle/package latest version of custom library in maven web project without updating pom.xml?

Tags: java, maven

I have a custom library - Dao.jar which contains the database persistence logic.
 
I push this jar to artifactory with new version each time there is a change in code as shown below :

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=C:\*****\target\Dao.jar -DgroupId=non-public.com.karthik -DartifactId=dao -Dversion=2.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

I have another maven web project which has a dependency on this jar. This jar is also packaged/bundled in the maven webapp project/war.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>non-public.com.karthik</groupId>
    <artifactId>dao</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Currently, I am changing the version of dao dependency in the pom.xml & re-building the maven webapp project each time a new version of Dao.jar is available in the artifactory.
Is there any option to build the maven project with the latest version of Dao.jar without manually changing the dependency version in the pom.xml?

Comment: Deploy the jar file into Artifactory and use your library based on the depdendency. furthermore you are violating the principle of imutable releases cause you changing several times the same jar file. The best practice is to change the version each time you change the jar file...

Comment: Upgrading a released version without changing the pom.xml is sorry to say that a desaster...cause no one will realize that there have been changes in the original jar file...nor is there any indication of that..

Comment: @khmarbaise I didn't understand your comments completely but what I am asking is whether there is any option/approach other than updating the version of Dao.jar dependency in pom.xml of the maven web project(WAR) each time a new version of custom library(Dao.jar) is pushed to artifactory. How to always package the latest jar in the maven web project? Create the Dao.jar as child project?

Answer (score 0):

When Maven searches for a dependency, it first checks the local repository (*~/.m2/repository*). If it's not found, it tries other resources, such as remote repositories defined in the POM file or in the settings file (*~/.m2/settings.xml*).

By that logic, if you try to use a version of a local project that's not yet installed to the local repository, Maven will never be able to find it to use in another project.

To avoid changing version numbers all the time and manually building both projects. You could create a parent POM for both projects. The parent would then be able to recognize that one of the child projects depends on the other and build them in the correct order.

Comment: Thanks for the response. If I create parent POM for both projects, then child project - Dao becomes a dependency for another child project(maven web project) . Can we define one child project as dependency for another child project?

Comment: @Karthik yes, the parent POM will automatically figure out which one to build first.

Comment: ok. I plan to create a parent POM with modules. The module order decides the order in which the child projects will be built. Am I right?

Comment: @Karthik Partly, but not necessarily. Whether the modules depend on each other also plays a role in determining the order.

Comment: Thanks. I have posted an answer based on your inputs. Let me know if anything is missing/needs be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Luciano's inputs, I have created a multi-module maven project/parent POM with 2 modules(dao & web)

Parent

```
<groupId>com.karthik</groupId>
<artifactId>test</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        ..........
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement> 
<modules>
    <module>web</module>
    <module>dao</module>
</modules>
```

Child module # 1 - dao

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.karthik</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>dao</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    .........   
  </dependencies>
```

Child module # 2 - web(declared dao dependency in POM)

```
 <parent>
        <groupId>com.karthik</groupId>
        <artifactId>test</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
 </parent>
 <artifactId>web</artifactId>
 <packaging>war</packaging>
 <dependencies>
      <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.karthik</groupId>
        <artifactId>dao</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      </dependency>
      ......... 
 </dependencies>
```

When I run **mvn package** command at root path of parent pom, both modules - web.war and dao.jar are built. This method ensures always the latest version of dao.jar is packaged in web.war.